# facing issue to print data of a variable outside of the if statement done programming using qt

Tags: c++, linux, qt

In Qt I'm trying to read some data using QStringList
like,
          input: 
           name:xxxxx
           id:yyyy
           college:zzzzz

```
       name:bbbb
       .....will repeat with the same keywords
```

So, I'm searching these data by QStringList with tokens split ":" then in if statement I'm checking the keywords whether contains "name" or "id" and  have fed data to QString. When after all data storage I'm appending these data like xxxx+yyyy+zzzz; these I'm trying to return as a QString then before this I'm trying to print appended string I'm getting data as

```
  example:- xxxxx, "", ""
           "" ,yyyyy,"" like this can anyone spot the issue would be helpful
```

Comment: How about https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve - create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how are you trying to do this without your code. If i get you right, you are doing something like this...

```
#include <QDebug>
#include <QStringList>

int main() {
    QStringList strings;

    strings.append("name:xxxxx");
    strings.append("id:yyyy");
    strings.append("college:zzzzz");

    QString name;
    QString college;
    QString id;

    foreach (const auto &str, strings) {
        if (str.contains("name")) {
            name = str.split(":").at(1);
        }

        if (str.contains("college")) {
            college = str.split(":").at(1);
        }

        if (str.contains("id")) {
            id = str.split(":").at(1);
        }
    }

    QString finalString = name + id + college;

    qDebug() << finalString;

    return 0;
}
```

Output is `"xxxxxyyyyzzzzz"`. I hope this helps.